# CEF3, Python -- nothing works when run from Eclipse, works from console

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, chromium-embedded

I just started trying out CEF3 (Chromium Embedded Framework) for Python and got it working -- but it only works when run from the console.

When I type "python ceftest.py" everything pops up nicely.  When I hit ctrl-11 in Eclipse to run it, the window pops up but nothing is displayed.  Minor annoyance as eventually this will be run from console, but in the mean time, for testing purposes, is there any way to have it work within Eclipse?  Is this because I have different paths to modules in console vs eclipse?  If so, how do I sync the two?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked logs, any errors?

Comment: There's actually nothing in either debug.log -- in home/CEFPython (which is where I import from in my script) or in usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cef3 which I think is where the console pulls from.  There also isn't a log file in my local working package, either.

Comment: Have you tried running one of official examples? Try wxpython.py.

Comment: Yes, they also work from console but not from Eclipse.  My code is actually just sample2.py adjusted with my URL, etc.